# Connect to a Windows server from my local computer using powershell

Tags: powershell

Ok, I've spent 2 hours trying to get this but I'm stuck.

I've just got a server with Windows 2008 R2 installed.
What I'd like to do is to connect to my windows server, from my laptop, using powershell.
Is this possible at all?
All the tutorials I've seen about windows remote connection talk about connections between the server and other computers in that environment.

Thanks!

Comment: You might get help if you explain what you mean by "connect" and post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yes of course this is possible. This is exactly what Powershell remoting is for. You need to add *a lot* more details about your environment and use case. That's nice you added some code, but what are the problems you're encountering with this so far? Setting up trusted hosts won't do anything for you unless you actually have delegation of credentials enabled in addition to having your target computer set up to receive fresh credentials. `-Value *` is very unsafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible!

This is what I had to do:

First, I had to make sure powershell remoting is enabled in both, my local computer and the server:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

Then, edit the local servers TrustedHosts configuration setting to allow access to your computer.

In your local computer type:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value yourserveripaddress -Force
```

In your server:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value yourlocalcomputername-Force
```

You can get your local computer name with the command: hostname

Almost done. Now run the following command:

```
 $cred = Get-Credential serverusername
```

A window will open, enter the server's admin name and password.

Finally, you can open a Powershell session using the following line:

```
 Enter-PSSession -ComputerName theserveripaddress -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Edited my answer to make TrustedHosts option more secure adding specific computer names